# AD 2003 -> kerberos failure

Tags: linux, apache, single-sign-on, kerberos

I'm trying to get a Single Sign On system working, but I keep on hitting the same error.
Here is a part of the logs:

### single sign on failure

> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:23 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1667): [client 10.29.0.153] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:23 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1667): [client 10.29.0.153] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:23 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1277): [client 10.29.0.153] Acquiring creds for HTTP/cognos.predika.be@PREDIKA.BE
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:23 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1424): [client 10.29.0.153] Verifying client data using KRB5 GSS-API
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:23 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1440): [client 10.29.0.153] Client didn't delegate us their credential
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:23 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1468): [client 10.29.0.153] Warning: received token seems to be NTLM, which isn't supported by the Kerberos module. Check your IE configuration.
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:23 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1138): [client 10.29.0.153] GSS-API major_status:00090000, minor_status:00000000
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:23 2011] [error] [client 10.29.0.153] gss_accept_sec_context() failed: Invalid token was supplied (, No error)

### login via basic auth

> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:31 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1667): [client 10.29.0.153] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:31 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1025): [client 10.29.0.153] Using HTTP/cognos.predika.be@PREDIKA.BE as server principal for password verification
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:31 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(714): [client 10.29.0.153] Trying to get TGT for user cognos03@PREDIKA.BE
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:31 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1110): [client 10.29.0.153] kerb_authenticate_user_krb5pwd ret=0 user=cognos03@PREDIKA.BE authtype=Basic
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:31 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1667): [client 10.29.0.153] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
> [Tue Dec 27 14:34:31 2011] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1605): [client 10.29.0.153] matched previous auth request

Does anyone understand what this means and how I should fix it?